# BSOD error Windows

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have been having a bad experience with Windows recently. I am not sure what is the cause.

My Motherboard and Processor is brand new, while I have already switched HDDs to no avail. I have reformated and reinstalled Win 8 numerous times already, but I always have these sort of problems:

- BSOD - IRQL not LESS or EQUAL && CRITICAL PROCESS DIED
- Can't Boot - I/O Error 0x000000e9 error and/or winload.exe has errors
- Windows is Generally slow (of the once in a blue moon that it does boot)

Thing is, I am able to run Linux *smoothly*.

What could be the cause?

Speccy: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/HPNKFWpkFOggITTtcTiFusj

EDIT - I cant give any more details about the BSOD because it doesnt boot anymore. However, these are the [previous logs](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/bsod-crashes-debugging/33189d1386724512-random-bsod-kernel-page-error-critical-process-died-sf_11-12-2013.zip)

Comment: I assume installing the Windows 8.1 update didn't solve anything.  The fact this problem happens with multiple hdds indicates a hardware problem.  Without more specific information about the BSOD I won't be able to narrow it down.

Comment: Start swapping/testing RAM.

Comment: Have you overclocked your PC?

Comment: you have Disk issues (DISK_HARDWARE_ERROR: There was error with disk hardware. (NTSTATUS) 0xc000000e = STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE (A device which does not exist was specified)). Check the HDD cables.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to attempt that I can think of.

1. Make sure there are no external devices attached (even USB keyboards etc) if it boots then plug them in and make sure all drivers are up to date.
2. Go to your bios screen and ensure all your drives are set up as SATA
3. Drivers drivers drivers (boot in safe mode if that works), since it runs Linux fine software is the likely culprit...pull everything down and work from the BIOS out.  Bios, processor, Mobo, GPU.

Hope one of these works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the following tool

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

It will give you additional info regarding the cause of your bsod.